# Windows send file to browser with the "Send to" shortcut

Tags: windows, file, browser, upload

I would like to use the "Send to" menu of Windows to **upload files** to a server. There is a lot of solutions to achieve that like ftp but I need to **use the default Web browser** of the computer.

I wrote a simple test script that is able to:

- Receive the files with their full path
- Open the browser to a specific page

My questions are the following:

1. Is it possible to send and action/arguments to the browser that allows it to access to this files ? If yes how does it works and is it cross-browser ?
2. My only requierement is to use the browser to upload the files but I can use any kind of third party software to pass the files to the browser. So is there any way to do that with a java applet or something similar ?

Thank you for your time !